# Using an upstream proxy only for certain URLs

Tags: nginx, proxy, squid

I'm configuring a transparent proxy for my home, and I want certain URLs to go through an upstream proxy.

I'm currently using Squid, but I'm open to other suggestions.

I've looked at Squid's cache_peer options, but none seems to serve my purposes.

Is this even possible?

**Edit:** I also have nginx on the proxy machine, so maybe I can use that?

Answer (score 0):

Using a proxy-autoconfig (.pac) file to direct the client system to the proxy server(s) lets you define what hosts and domains get proxied through which server.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I want to keep the transparent proxy part, because I want to use desktop apps which don't support configuring a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [cache_peer_domain](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer_domain/) or [cache_peer_access](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer_access/) directives can do what you want.